# Clojure (or Java) and Cocoa: NSStatusBar with text-based NSStatuItem on OS X

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, clojure

I'm writing a Clojure app with a NSStatusBar UI on OS X. What is the best practice for this?

I'm aware of [ClojureM](https://github.com/joshaber/clojurem) that compiles Clojure to Objective-C (based on ClojureScript), but that's not what I'm looking for. My app will run on a JVM and just needs to talk to NSStatusBar.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481504/creating-an-nsstatusitem-menubar-app-in-java

Comment: Thanks @DiegoBasch. I see that java.awt.TrayIcon is limited to tray items based on images, but I actually need a text tray item. Worst case, I can generate images from the text I need to display but that would be ugly. Edited my question to add clarification.