# Install4j launcher does not run (MacOS)

Tags: java, install4j

I've created a Java SWT app based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13481504/creating-an-nsstatusitem-menubar-app-in-java) post. I generate the installer and install on my system. When I launch the app, it simply bounces in the dock. When I run the jar manually it works fine (I see the menubar icon). I put a println statement at the beginning of the main method to make sure the java code is executed. When I run ./MacOS/JavaApplicationStub on the command line from the app directory, there is no output. This leads me to believe the main class is not being executed. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had to uncheck uses SWT or QT and this fixed the problem. Not sure why that was breaking the launcher.

Comment: The post you linked in your question shows an AWT application, not a SWT application.